# Create Multiple Pagination in One Page Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

i am new bie in codeigniter. how to create multiple pagination in one page. i have tried to make it, but only one pagination that success. in other pagination getting error.Please help me. i have read some suggestion that must using javascript or ajax. but i don't know how to make it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax and javascript, but that is not necessary. Instead, you could pass parameters to your controller which specify the number of items to display and the offset to start with. For example, if you want to display 20 items per page, you would start with a "count" of 20 and an offset of 0, then on the next page you would have a "count" of 20 and an offset of 20, then a count of 20 and an offset of 40, and so on. Passing these variables makes it easy to pass them along to a SQL query, too. The query just pulls the items from the database and the correct items are then displayed in the view.

All of this logic is not specific to codeignitor, either, this is essentially how any system that uses pagination would work.